# Show that this infimum is greater than zero

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $K=[a_1,b_1]\times\dots \times [a_d,b_d]$ be a closed rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and suppose that $K\subset\cup_{i=1}^n R_i$, where each $R_i=(c_{i1},d_{i1}) \times \dots \times (c_{id},d_{id})$ is an open rectangle $\mathbb{R}^d$.

For $x \in K$, let $$\delta(x) = \sup \{ r>0 : B(x,r) \subset R_i \text{ for some } i\}$$

where the ball is taken with respect to the maximum norm $||x||_{\infty}=\max\{|x_1|,\dots,|x_d|\}$. Let $\delta= \inf\{\delta(x):x \in K\}$.  I want to show that $\delta>0$ and that for any $x$ there is some $R_i$ such that $B(k,\delta) \subset R_i$.

EDIT: It was suggested in the comments that Lebesgue's number lemma could do it. But is there a more direct way?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $K$ is compact so you could apply the Lebesgue covering number, e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok I will look at it. Do you understand the approach suggested by Alan below? Am not sure I understand what he means.

Answer (score 1):

You can go directly.   You have a finite length of $K$ and a finite amount of $R_i$'s.   Each possible combination gets you a closed ball (rectangles are balls in the max norm) that lives inside an open ball.   Thus,  there's an $\epsilon>0$  distance between the two,  so you have each supremum involve is bounded below by $\frac \epsilon 2$.   Take the minimum of all of those finite values, and that will be a lower bound on your final set

Comment: What do you mean by a combination?

Comment: @Alphie Sorry,  I've been distracted.  The different ways each fitting each closed interval of K into an interval of the R's